# ODBC SQLDetDiagRec returns unexpected messages

Tags: c++, odbc

I'm learning how to do a ODBC connection using C++ and I seem to be stuck on diagnostics.

I make a connection call using SQLDriverConnect and receive an SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO result. I'd like to see what messages are there.

My function for printing errors is as follows:

```
void show_error(unsigned int handletype, const SQLHANDLE& handle){
    SQLWCHAR sqlstate[1024];
    SQLWCHAR message[1024];
    if (SQL_SUCCESS == SQLGetDiagRec(handletype, handle, 1, sqlstate, NULL, message, 1024, NULL))
    {
        cout << "Message: " << message << "\nSQLSTATE: " << sqlstate << endl;
    }
}
```

The resources I'm learning from all state that the message result from SQLDetDiagRec should be a useful string value but my function returns:

```
Message: 002EE160
SQLState: 002ED960
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to finally find a solution to this. It turns out that ODBC sometimes uses Wide Character types (SQLWCHAR instead of SQLCHAR). I'm not sure why.  I'm guessing it depends on the library you're using.

If using SQLWCHAR std::cout will not be able to print the wide values. To do so you need std::wcout.

So the proper way to print this would be:

```
void show_error(unsigned int handletype, const SQLHANDLE& handle){
    SQLWCHAR sqlstate[1024];
    SQLWCHAR message[1024];
    if (SQL_SUCCESS == SQLGetDiagRec(handletype, handle, 1, sqlstate, NULL, message, 1024, NULL))
    {
        std::wcout << "Message: " << message << "\nSQLSTATE: " << sqlstate << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You look to be printing the addresses of sqlstate and message instead of their contents.